# Product Key letters are always typed as capital during the Windows installation

Tags: windows-xp, installation, capslock

When I install Windows XP Professional on my machine, while entering the product key, letters are always typed `CAPITAL`.

It doesn't change by toggling the Caps Lock key. How do I solve it?

Comment: Are you trying to enter the code in ALLCAPS or are you trying to enter it in lowercase, or are you getting an error message. Please clarify what the problem is exactly.

Comment: As music2myear said, **have you actually tried to continue** or does the key not work this way?

Answer (score 6):

This cannot be done as the keys are always converted to uppercase by the installer.
Thus, if there is any error it can never occur due to case of the letters.

It could be an issue with the key itself.

Additionally, check out for the version of XP you are installating. Keys meant for
Windows XP Home edition will not work for XP professional Business edition.